# class, __init__ и def подскажите логику. Вопрос простой :-)

Tags: python, классы

Имею код следующего вида:

```
class testirovanie:
    eins=None
    zwei=None

    def __init__(self,ferst=None, second=None):
        self.eins=ferst
        self.zwei=second
    
    def test(self, odin=eins, dva=zwei):
        pervi=odin
        vtoroi=dva
        print(pervi,vtoroi)
```

В моём понимании должно быть так:

```
#IN:
testirovanie(1,2).test()
testirovanie().test(1,2)

#OUT:
1 2
1 2
```

По факту имею:

```
#OUT:
None None
1 2
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём заблуждаюсь и что нужно сделать чтобы:

```
# При IN:
testirovanie(1,2).test()

#Иметь OUT:
1 2
```

Comment: Вы нигде и никогда не считываете `self.eins` и `self.zwei`, а вместо этого при создании метода аргументы `odin` и `dva` получают значения по умолчанию из переменных `eins` и `zwei`, которые на момент создания метода имеют значение `None`

Comment: Причём тут вообще наследование?

Comment: Я думал что **self.eins** и **self.zwei** из **__init__** обновляет **eins** и **zwei** . Буду признателен если покажите как надо :-). Сижу думаю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Немного не понимаю цели кода, но укажу на некоторые детали

1. Метод `__init__()` срабатывает всегда, когда вы создаете экземпляр класса, то есть когда вызываете `testirovanie()`
2. Класс принято называть английским существительным с заглавной буквы `class Test:`
3. Экземпляр класса будет содержать те данные, которые вы укажите в `__init__()`, но они будут относиться только к одному экземпляру и доступны по ключевому слову `self` в методах класса. Если ваша реализация метода не содержит `self` - это значит, что определенные переменные не имеют ничего общего с полями класса. `eins` не то же самое, что `self.eins` для всех реализаций класса.
4. Статические поля определенные в самом начале класса становятся не доступными (через экземпляр), если вы используете те же имена для не статических полей в методе `__init__()`. Здесь вот мне не понятно, что вы пытаетесь реализовать.

с учетом вышесказанного

```py
class Test:
    eins = "None из статического атрибута eins"
    zwei = "None из статического атрибута zwei"

    def __init__(self,ferst=None, second=None):
        self.eins=ferst
        self.zwei=second    

    def test(self, odin=eins, dva=zwei):
        print(f"это то что содержит экземпляр {self.eins}, {self.zwei}")
        # Вот этот участок кода забирает статические поля по умолчанию
        # или забирает указанные значения при вызове данного метода
        pervi=odin
        vtoroi=dva
        print(f"print из test {pervi},{vtoroi}")
```

Обратимся к полям. Если мы используем экземпляр класса, тогда и поле мы должны указывать у экземпляра класса. Но при этом статическое значение атрабута в классе останется неизменным

```py
t = Test(1,2) 
print(t.eins, Test.eins)
(1, 'None из статического атрибута eins')
```

То есть надо понимать, что если вы хотите работать с переменной конкретного экземпляра, то ее надо использовать через экземпляр класса.

Что же с методом `test`. Я разделил значения и дал комментарии, чтобы было понятно откуда, что прилетает

```py
>>> Test().test()
это то что содержит экземпляр None, None
print из test None из статического атрибута eins,None из статического атрибута zwei
>>> Test(1,2).test()
это то что содержит экземпляр 1, 2
print из test None из статического атрибута eins,None из статического атрибута zwei
>>> Test().test(1,2)
это то что содержит экземпляр None, None
print из test 1,2
>>> Test(1,2).test(1,2)
это то что содержит экземпляр 1, 2
print из test 1,2
```

Обратимся к последнему примеру и подчеркнем, что значения 1 и 2 не имеют ничего общего с полями класса, ни с какими. Это просто значения переданные в метод.

Ожидаете вы наверное вот это

```py
class Test:
    def __init__(self, first=None, second=None):
        self.first = first
        self.second = second

    def test(self, first=None, second=None):
        if first and second:
            self.first = first
            self.second = second
        print(self.first, self.second)
```

вывод

```py
>>> Test().test()
None None
>>> Test(1,2).test()
1 2
>>> Test().test(1,2)
1 2
>>> Test(1,2).test(1,2)
1 2
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за развёрнутый ответ! Цель видится такой: в классе должно быть много методов которые по умолчанию должны работать с переменными заданными на уровне класса, но в случае особой необходимости хочется их менять на уровне метода.

Comment: Изначально не нравилось писать self. перед каждой переменной. Думал можно облегчить код сославшись на атрибут заданный через init :-(
Жалко что почему то нельзся сослаться на значние переменной в параметрах и использовать такую конструкцию


**def test(self, first=self.eins, second=self.zwei):**

Comment: @НикитаТимоходцев здесь логика проста: зачем присваивать, то что уже есть в экземпляре. Методы принимают на вход внешние данные, остаьлное уже все есть в экземаляре

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:

```
class MyTest:
    eins = None
    zwei = None

    def __init__(self, ferst=None, second=None):
        self.eins = ferst
        self.zwei = second
    
    def test(self, odin=None, dva=None):
        if odin: self.eins = odin 
        if dva: self.zwei = dva 
        print(self.eins, self.zwei)


test_1 = MyTest(1, 2)
test_1.test()
test_1.test(3, 7)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: есть ли смысл определения статических eins и zwei? Они все равно нигде не используются в данной реализации